# Advanced SQL: Sum of sales between a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to get the sum of sales for a specific product between  a date range. Unfortunately, the sum of sales from the results for both dates are the same. By right the total sales on 2019/01/01 is 5000 and the total sales on following day 2019/01/02 is 3000. The results showed total sales which is 8000 for both days. Which is wrong. Any expert can help to improve is this query?

```
Declare @BusinessDate datetime ='2019-01-01'
Declare @end datetime ='2019-01-02'
DECLARE @StoreId int = 100
SELECT  [Terminals].[Id] AS [TerminalId],
        [Terminals].[StoreId],
        [EOD].[Id] AS [EODId],
        SUM([Sales].[SalesAmount]) AS [SalesAmount],
        [EOD].BusinessDate
FROM    [CEPP]..[Stores] WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN [CEPP]..[Terminals] WITH (NOLOCK)
 ON     [Stores].[Id] = [Terminals].[StoreId]
        AND [Terminals].[MWorkFlowStatusId] = 2
        AND ([Terminals].[MStatusId] = 1
        OR ([Terminals].[MStatusId] = 0
        AND [Terminals].[SuspendedDate] > @BusinessDate ))
        LEFT JOIN [EndOfDays] AS [EOD] WITH (NOLOCK)
 ON     [Terminals].[Id] = [EOD].[TerminalId]
        AND [EOD].[BusinessDate] >= @BusinessDate and [EOD].[BusinessDate]<=@end
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT SUM([Products].[Deno]) AS [SalesAmount]
            FROM [SalesOrders] AS [SO] WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN [SalesTransactions] AS [ST] WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  [SO].[Id] = [ST].[SalesOrderId]
                LEFT JOIN [VoidOrders] AS [VO] WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN [VoidTransactions] AS [VT] WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  [VO].[Id] = [VT].[VoidOrderId]
            ON  [SO].[DealerId] = [VO].[DealerId]
                AND [SO].[StoreId] = [VO].[StoreId]
                AND [SO].[TerminalId] = [VO].[TerminalId]
                AND [ST].[ProductId] = [VT].[ProductId]
                AND [ST].[SerialNo] = [VT].[SerialNo]
                AND [ST].[BusinessDate] = [VT].[BusinessDate]
                AND [VT].[MVoidTypeId] = 1
                INNER JOIN [CEPP].[dbo].[Products] WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  [ST].[ProductId] = [Products].[Id]
            WHERE [EOD].[Id] IS NOT NULL
                AND [VT].[SerialNo] IS NULL
                AND [SO].[TerminalId] = [Terminals].[Id]
                AND [ST].[BusinessDate] >= @BusinessDate and [ST].[BusinessDate] <= @end
        ) AS [Sales]
WHERE  [Stores].[DealerId] = 1 AND (@StoreId IS NULL OR [Terminals].[StoreId] = @StoreId)
GROUP BY [Terminals].[Id], [Terminals].[StoreId], [EOD].[Id], [Stores].[Code], [Terminals].[Code],[EOD].BusinessDate
ORDER BY ISNULL([EOD].[Id], 0), [Stores].[Code], [Terminals].[Code]
```

The unexpected results I got is :

```
TerminalId  StoreId   EODId   SalesAmount   BusinessDate
  21598      100     5427531    8000.00    2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
  21598      100     5427532    8000.00    2019-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

The results should be like this:

```
TerminalId  StoreId   EODId   SalesAmount   BusinessDate
  21598      100     5427531    5000.00    2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
  21598      100     5427532    3000.00    2019-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Try casting all BusinessDate columns to Date `CAST(BusinessDate AS DATE)`  see if this would give you the results you need.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see at a glance and without test data, is that the SUM([Products].[Deno]) is being performed in the CROSS APPLY irrespective of any GROUP BY you have in the outer query. Hence why you're getting SUM([Sales].[SalesAmount]) to equal 8000 for each output row.

Refactor the CROSS APPLY subquery to aggregate SUM([Products].[Deno]) with respect to a GROUP BY and join back to the main table by the GROUP BY predicates to your outer query.

Answer (score 0):

AND [EOD].[BusinessDate] >= @BusinessDate and [EOD].[BusinessDate]<=@end

This part looks very suspicious to me. I think it should be something like

[EOD].[BusinessDate] = [Sales].[Date]

If that does not resolve your problem, please provide us with scripts for creation of tables and test data. That way it's much easier to investigate query.